# nested regexes in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking to write a perl program which looks for the following keywords in a pattern:

```
`lint64 | strictlintflags64 | cflags64.`
```

Once I ensure that one of these patterns are present in the searched text, I dig deeper to see if there are any anomalies hidden in the searched text.
The anomalies are the same words **without** the string '64' appended in the end.
That is:

```
lint | strictlintflags | cflags
```

For example:
Pure string would be:

```
"asd:   lint64_SRCS"
```

Anomaly-ridden string would be:

```
"CFLAGS += $(CCVERBOSE)lint:     lint64_PROG"
```

Here is the test code I wrote to detect if a particular search text has an anomaly:

```
#!/usr/perl5/bin/perl -w

require 5.6.1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use locale;

my $string = "CFLAGS += $(CCVERBOSE)lint:     lint64_PROG";
#my $string2 = "asd:   lint64_SRCS";

if ($string =~ m/lint64|strictlintflags64|cflags64/ig) {
    if ($string =~ m/lint(?!64)|strictlintflags(?!64)|cflags(?!64)/ig) {
        print "anomaly-ridden"
    }
    else {
        print "pure";
    }
}
else {
    print "garbage";
}
```

This code detects $string2 correctly as a pure string.

Unfortunately, `$string` detected as "pure" instead of "anomaly-ridden".

Any clues as to why ?
Also, if I comment out the outer-if loop, the `$string` is detected correctly as a `"anomaly-ridden"` string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the /g flags; they are telling it to do the first match, then try the second match from where the first match ended.

Comment: thank you for explaining this. I had no idea what perl was doing under the hood.